# ArcMap 10.6. Input Features of any tool causes software to crash

Tags: arcmap, tools

Any tool I use in ArcMap crashes the entire program when I click the folder next to the "input features". Literally any geoprocessing tool. I'm not sure why this is happening, or what relevant information I can provide on how to diagnose and fix this problem. Any tips on settings I can manage to fix this issue?

I don't know if it's relevant or not, but before this started happening, tools would successfully run, but the outputs wouldnt appear in the output folder.

I should also note that it works fine if I use the drop-down menu for input features, which only shows features that are already in the table of contents. But pushing the folder icon to navigate directories and select new features is what's causing the software to crash.

Comment: By "crashes" do you mean that you get the "Serious Application Error" dialog, or something else?

Comment: I get the spinning wheel for literally hours (eight hours is the longest I waited), then when I click the exit box I get the "Arcmap is not responding" box with the option to exit

Comment: I would not describe that as a crash. I think people generally say that ArcMap has hung or won't stop spinning. Perhaps search on those terms or for the quickest fix consider uninstalling and reinstalling.

Comment: It's been a long time since I had this problem but I seem to recall it being due to one of the entries under "Folder Connections" in ArcCatalog being inaccessible, for example a mapped network drive that is no longer available. Try removing removing any Folder Connections in ArcCatalog that you don't use or are no longer valid paths.

Comment: Dan C that's what the problem was. Removing all the folder connections allows me to select input features without arcmap freezing. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Dan C in the comments section has the solution: Remove all entries under folder connections (or ones that no longer have valid paths, I just removed them all to be safe) and this issue will be resolved.